# Deploying Problems with Tizen Studio - Certificate Error -14

Tags: tizen

Since a week i have massive problem to deploy apps to my Samsung Gear S3
I tried following points to solve this problem but without any success:

1. Clean install of Tizen Studio.
2. Package Manager -> Tizen SDK Tools
3. Package Manager -> installed all wearables -> samsung certificate extension
4. Package Manager -> installed all wearables -> samsung wearable extension
5. open project (web based app)
6. open device manager and connect the watch
7. open certificate manager and add a certificate with a samsung account.
8. deploy the app
   Error -14

**Watch Informations**

Watch: Samsung Gear S3,
Model-Number: SM-R760,
Tizen 3.0.0.2,
Softwareversion: R760XXU2CRH1,
developlmentmode: ON,
debugging: ON

Does anyone has an idea how i can solve this issue?

Best regards,
doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

Firmwareupgrade to newest version:
connect watch to WLAN and make the update

then add a new samsung certificate. after that the problem was solved.